# Why does compiling this code result in a syntax error?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datarow

I wrote the following code but i am getting the error as i mentioned can any one tell

```
protected void btnGenerate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataRow[] dRow;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    foreach (GridViewRow grRow in grdACH.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox chkItem = (CheckBox)grRow.FindControl("checkRec");
        if (chkItem.Checked)
        {
            chkItm = true;
            chkcnt++;
            strBankTypeID = ((Label)grRow.FindControl("lblBankType")).Text.ToString();
            strBnkArray.Append(strBankTypeID);
            strBnkArray.Append(",");
        }
    }
    oEmpDeposits.getEmpDepositDetails(out local_ds, strFedTaxId, PayperiodNumber, PayrollYear, strPayFreqType);

for (int i = 0; i < local_ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        string strTrim = strBnkArray.ToString().TrimEnd(',');
        strTrim = "BankAccountTypeID='" + strTrim[i] + "'";
        if (strTrim.Contains("BankAccountTypeID=',"))
        {
            strTrim = "BankAccountTypeID='" + strTrim[i] + "'";
        }

        dRow = local_ds.Tables[0].Select(strTrim);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you getting the error ?

Comment: Please would you post the full error message?

Comment: I guess we need to know what strBnkArray is *before* the button is clicked to answer this. The best would be if you put a breakpoint on the Select line, and post what the content of strBnkArray is at that point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax error comes from this statement:

```
dRow = local_ds.Tables[0].Select(strBnkArray.ToString().TrimEnd(','));
```

There is something wrong with the *expression* you are trying to use.

That expression is made up from this:

```
strBnkArray.ToString().TrimEnd(',')
```

Check what that is and you find the answer. Like this perhaps:

```
string mySelectStatement = strBnkArray.ToString().TrimEnd(',');
dRow = local_ds.Tables[0].Select(mySelectStatement);
```

Comment: a small help i modified my code as posted but for the 2nd time in loop i am getting `,` how can i skip this and print the next preceding to , i,e assume my string is C,D i would like to check for only C and D skipping `,`

Answer (score 0):

WHy don't you use `ArrayList` instead of String array. So that it will be easy to manipulate

Sample

```
if (chkItem.Checked)
{
  chkItm = true;
  chkcnt++;
  strBankTypeID += ((Label)grRow.FindControl("lblBankType")).Text.ToString(); 
  ArrayList lstArray=new ArrayList();
  lstArray.Add(strBankTypeID);
}
```

Later

```
 oEmpDeposits.getEmpDepositDetails(out local_ds, strFedTaxId, PayperiodNumber, PayrollYear, strPayFreqType);

    for (int i = 0; i < lstArray.Count; i++)
    {
        //string strTrim = strBnkArray.ToString().TrimEnd(',');
        strBankAccntType = "BankAccountTypeID='" + lstArray[i].ToString() + "'";
        dRow = local_ds.Tables[0].Select(strBankAccntType);
    }
```